# Is it possible to have asymmetric serialization and de-serialization using Jackson JSON?

Tags: java, json, jackson

Say I have this JSON

```
{
  "propertA" : "test"
}
```

gets deserialized into an object using this class

```
public static class MyClass
{
  private String propertya;

  @JsonGetter( "propertya" )
  public String getPropertya() { return this.propertya; }

  @JsonSetter( "propertyA" )
  public void setPropertya( String a ){ this.propertya = a };
}
```

I used @JsonGetter so I could serialize that object instance into the following:

```
{
  "properta" : "test"
}
```

But it didn't, I still get the following:

```
{
  "propertA" : "test"
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I was expecting that @JsonGetter will serialize my class instance property "propertya" into "propertya" but it seems @JsonSetter took over the control when serializing. What exactly @JsonGetter does? It looks like it's not influencing how my object will be serialized.

Comment: `I was expecting that @JsonGetter will deserialize my class field "propertyA"`, do you mean @JsonSetter here ?

Comment: I meant "serialze". Updated the question.

Comment: API [doc](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.3.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonSetter.html) stated exactly your use case. Maybe you are using a faulty version ?

Comment: I'm using Jackson 2.2.2. Not sure if that's the faulty one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated to version 2.4.0 and it worked. But I would have to add @JsonIgnore to fields which is fine.

With 2.4.0, the following code should work:

```
public static class MyClass
{
  @JsonIgnore
  private String propertya;

  @JsonGetter( "propertya" )
  public String getPropertya() { return this.propertya; }

  @JsonSetter( "propertyA" )
  public void setPropertya( String a ){ this.propertya = a };
}
```

Comment: Exactly, I was about to write about that the issue has been fixed in 2.4.0.