# How does a higher version of a library in build.sbt affect Play (that uses lower version)?

Tags: playframework, sbt, playframework-2.2

So here's a part of my build definition:

```
libraryDependencies in Global ++= Seq(
  ...
  "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-core"        % "2.4.0",
  "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind"    % "2.4.0",
  "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-annotations" % "2.4.0",
  ...
)
```

I'm using Play Framework 2.2.2 and by default it is using `com.fasterxml.jackson.core` artifacts in version 2.2.2.

How does it affect my play server if I include an existing library with a higher version in my build file?

UPDATE:

I had to do it because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24076474/is-it-possible-to-have-asymmetric-serialization-and-de-serialization-using-jacks). I'm not sure if it's going to affect only our application or will it affect the entire play stack.

Answer (score 0):

It depends if API (public methods/fields you call from your app) is compatible accross the different versions.

If not you will probably get `NoSuchMethodError` at runtime.